# Invalid state store content after aborted transaction with exactly_once and standby replicas after task migration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

we have a simple command id deduplication mechanism based on Kafka Streams State Stores. It stores command ids from the past hour in *persistentWindowStore*. We encountered a problem with the store if there's an exception thrown later in that topology.
We run 3 nodes using docker, each with multiple threads set for this particular Streams Application. The flow is as follows:

- message is consumed on node 1 Thread-1 (A):

```
2020-04-16 07:26:19.144 DEBUG 1 --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.f.c.s.validation.CommandIdValidator  : CommandId: mnl_cmd_1cd3a7c9-56ef-4c08-a312-d9b69681726a is not a duplicate.
2020-04-16 07:26:19.144  INFO 1 --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.f.c.s.v.CommandIdValidationUtils     : Putting commandId in store: mnl_cmd_1cd3a7c9-56ef-4c08-a312-d9b69681726a 1587013200000
2020-04-16 07:26:19.153  INFO 1 --- [-StreamThread-1] g.f.l.s.v.XXXXValidationHandler : 
Exception in thread "XXXXXXProcessor-53816dfa-6ebf-47ad-864c-0fbcb61dc51c-StreamThread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exponent value: -5
Failed to process stream task 1_2 due to the following error
Shutting down
Unclean shutdown of all active tasks
Flushing all stores registered in the state manager
```

First node in the topology analyses if this is a duplicate, if not puts it in the state store. Next topology node throws an exception. As a result, transaction is aborted, offsets are not committed. I double checked for the changelog topic - relevant messages are not committed.

- the task was migrated to another instance, state store is recreated, message is consumed on node 2 Thread-2 (B):

```
2020-04-16 07:26:43.399 DEBUG 1 --- [-StreamThread-2] c.g.f.c.s.validation.CommandIdValidator  : CommandId: mnl_cmd_1cd3a7c9-56ef-4c08-a312-d9b69681726a is not a duplicate.
2020-04-16 07:26:43.400  INFO 1 --- [-StreamThread-2] c.g.f.c.s.v.CommandIdValidationUtils     : Putting commandId in store: mnl_cmd_1cd3a7c9-56ef-4c08-a312-d9b69681726a 1587013200000
2020-04-16 07:26:43.425  INFO 1 --- [-StreamThread-2] g.f.l.s.v.XXXXValidationHandler : 
Exception in thread "XXXXXXProcessor-d069f877-90ff-4ecf-bfbf-3b2bd0e20eac-StreamThread-2" java.lang.RuntimeException: XXXX
```

Again same story, transaction aborted.

- **the task was migrated to node 1 Thread-2 again** (C) where Thread-1 already failed:

```
2020-04-16 07:26:55.655  INFO 1 --- [-StreamThread-2] c.g.f.c.s.v.CommandIdValidationUtils     : next: KeyValue(1587013200000, mnl_cmd_1cd3a7c9-56ef-4c08-a312-d9b69681726a)
2020-04-16 07:26:55.655  WARN 1 --- [-StreamThread-2] c.g.f.c.s.validation.CommandIdValidator  : Command duplicate detected. Command id mnl_cmd_1cd3a7c9-56ef-4c08-a312-d9b69681726a
```

We analysed task restoration logs and all seems normal, aborted transactions were skipped:
`Skipping aborted record batch from partition`

However, the rocks db for this task contains the command id:

```
docker cp 134d4f6f82cf:/tmp/kafka-streams/XXXXXXProcessor/1_0/COMMAND_ID_STORE/COMMAND_ID_STORE.1587013200000 .
ldb --db=COMMAND_ID_STORE.1587013200000 scan
mnl_cmd_1cd3a7c9-56ef-4c08-a312-d9b69681726a : mnl_cmd_1cd3a7c9-56ef-4c08-a312-d9b69681726a
mnl_cmd_c51cbb71-0274-44c6-b016-976add743fe6 : mnl_cmd_c51cbb71-0274-44c6-b016-976add743fe6
```

**Our understanding is that even though the transaction was aborted on node 1 (A), the rocks db entry wasn't cleaned afterwards, and during (C) another thread fetched data from already existing rocks db (after all, the disk path is connected with the task, not thread). We are not sure what happens with persisted store during task restoration or during a task failure. According to us, this situation breaks exactly-once semantics, as the state store is not in sync with changelog topic.**

Is it a wrong configuration at our side/wrong assumptions? A bug? We tried changing the store to *inMemoryWindowStore* and it seems to solve the problem. But we'd like to understand this behaviour as we heavily rely on state stores.

We use Java 11, kafka clients 4.1 and spring-kafka 2.4.5. We rolled back to kafka clients 2.3.1 and the problem persists.

EDIT we performed some more tests with configuration changes and after  changing `num.standby.replicas = 1` to `num.standby.replicas = 0` the problem disappeared. From logs it looks like that standby state is created properly, i.e. aborted messages are not taken into account, but the state on disk gets corrupted nevertheless, which is quite easy to reproduce. 
One more analysis:
 - Node A Thread-2 handles the message, crashes
 - Node B Thread-2 is the standy replica, takes over, crashes
 - Node B Thread-1 takes over, detects a duplicate

EDIT 2
detailed logs relevant to checkpoint files. At first, a valid command is sent, then an invalid one (hence, a changelog topic is not empty).

```
NODE_3 2020-04-15 21:06:14.470 TRACE 1 --- [-StreamThread-2] o.a.k.s.p.i.ProcessorStateManager        : stream-thread [XXXXProcessor-94f7be8e-beec-411f-b4ec-9031527bccdf-StreamThread-2] task [1_2] Checkpointable offsets read from checkpoint: {}
NODE_3 2020-04-15 21:06:19.413 TRACE 1 --- [-StreamThread-2] o.a.k.s.p.i.ProcessorStateManager        : stream-thread [XXXXProcessor-94f7be8e-beec-411f-b4ec-9031527bccdf-StreamThread-2] task [1_2] Restoring state store COMMAND_ID_STORE from changelog topic XXXXProcessor-COMMAND_ID_STORE-changelog at checkpoint null
NODE_3 2020-04-15 21:06:28.470 TRACE 1 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.ProcessorStateManager        : stream-thread [XXXXProcessor-94f7be8e-beec-411f-b4ec-9031527bccdf-StreamThread-1] standby-task [1_2] Checkpointable offsets read from checkpoint: {}
NODE_3 2020-04-15 21:06:29.634 TRACE 1 --- [-StreamThread-2] o.a.k.s.s.internals.OffsetCheckpoint     : Writing tmp checkpoint file /tmp/kafka-streams/XXXXProcessor/1_2/.checkpoint.tmp
NODE_3 2020-04-15 21:06:29.640 TRACE 1 --- [-StreamThread-2] o.a.k.s.s.internals.OffsetCheckpoint     : Swapping tmp checkpoint file /tmp/kafka-streams/XXXXProcessor/1_2/.checkpoint.tmp /tmp/kafka-streams/XXXXProcessor/1_2/.checkpoint
NODE_3 2020-04-15 21:11:15.909 TRACE 1 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.s.internals.OffsetCheckpoint     : Writing tmp checkpoint file /tmp/kafka-streams/XXXXProcessor/1_2/.checkpoint.tmp
NODE_3 2020-04-15 21:11:15.912 TRACE 1 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.s.internals.OffsetCheckpoint     : Swapping tmp checkpoint file /tmp/kafka-streams/XXXXProcessor/1_2/.checkpoint.tmp /tmp/kafka-streams/XXXXProcessor/1_2/.checkpoint

NODE_1 log1:2020-04-15 21:11:33.942 DEBUG 1 --- [-StreamThread-2] c.g.f.c.s.validation.CommandIdValidator  : CommandId: mnl_cmd_9f1752da-45b7-4ef7-9ef8-209d826530bc is not a duplicate.

NODE_3 2020-04-15 21:11:47.195 TRACE 1 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.s.internals.OffsetCheckpoint     : Writing tmp checkpoint file /tmp/kafka-streams/XXXXProcessor/1_2/.checkpoint.tmp
NODE_3 2020-04-15 21:11:47.233 TRACE 1 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.s.internals.OffsetCheckpoint     : Swapping tmp checkpoint file /tmp/kafka-streams/XXXXProcessor/1_2/.checkpoint.tmp /tmp/kafka-streams/XXXXProcessor/1_2/.checkpoint
NODE_3 2020-04-15 21:11:49.075 TRACE 1 --- [-StreamThread-2] o.a.k.s.p.i.ProcessorStateManager        : stream-thread [XXXXProcessor-94f7be8e-beec-411f-b4ec-9031527bccdf-StreamThread-2] task [1_2] Restoring state store COMMAND_ID_STORE from changelog topic XXXXProcessor-COMMAND_ID_STORE-changelog at checkpoint 1
NODE_3 2020-04-15 21:11:49.436 TRACE 1 --- [-StreamThread-2] o.a.k.s.p.i.StoreChangelogReader         : stream-thread [XXXXProcessor-94f7be8e-beec-411f-b4ec-9031527bccdf-StreamThread-2] Found checkpoint 1 from changelog XXXXProcessor-COMMAND_ID_STORE-changelog-2 for store COMMAND_ID_STORE.

NODE_3 2020-04-15 21:11:52.023 DEBUG 1 --- [-StreamThread-2] c.g.f.c.s.validation.CommandIdValidator  : CommandId: mnl_cmd_9f1752da-45b7-4ef7-9ef8-209d826530bc is not a duplicate.
NODE_3 2020-04-15 21:11:53.683 ERROR 1 --- [-StreamThread-2] o.a.k.s.p.i.AssignedStreamsTasks         : stream-thread [XXXXProcessor-94f7be8e-beec-411f-b4ec-9031527bccdf-StreamThread-2] Failed to process stream task 1_2 due to the following error: java.lang.RuntimeException

NODE_3 2020-04-15 21:12:05.346 TRACE 1 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.ProcessorStateManager        : stream-thread [XXXXProcessor-94f7be8e-beec-411f-b4ec-9031527bccdf-StreamThread-1] task [1_2] Restoring state store COMMAND_ID_STORE from changelog topic XXXXProcessor-COMMAND_ID_STORE-changelog at checkpoint 1
NODE_3 2020-04-15 21:12:05.562 TRACE 1 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StoreChangelogReader         : stream-thread [XXXXProcessor-94f7be8e-beec-411f-b4ec-9031527bccdf-StreamThread-1] Found checkpoint 1 from changelog XXXXProcessor-COMMAND_ID_STORE-changelog-2 for store COMMAND_ID_STORE.

NODE_3 2020-04-15 21:12:06.424  WARN 1 --- [-StreamThread-1] c.g.f.c.s.validation.CommandIdValidator  : Command duplicate detected. Command id mnl_cmd_9f1752da-45b7-4ef7-9ef8-209d826530bc
```

Thanks for you help.

*Code operating on the COMMAND_ID_STORE (similar to an example from Kafka Streams)*

Adding state store

```
    WindowBytesStoreSupplier storeSupplier = Stores.persistentWindowStore(storeName,
        RETENTION,
        WINDOW_SIZE,
        true);
    StoreBuilder<WindowStore<String, String>> storeBuilder = Stores
        .windowStoreBuilder(storeSupplier, Serdes.String(), Serdes.String());
    streamsBuilder.addStateStore(storeBuilder);
```

Fetching

```
public static boolean isCommandIdDuplicate(String commandId, WindowStore<String, String> commandIdStore) {
    long previousHourStart = DateTimeUtils.previousHourStart();

    final WindowStoreIterator<String> storeIterator = commandIdStore
        .fetch(commandId, previousHourStart, DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis());
    final boolean hasNext = storeIterator.hasNext();
    log.info("hasNext: {}", hasNext);
    while (storeIterator.hasNext()) {
      log.info("next: {}", storeIterator.next());
    }
    storeIterator.close();
    return hasNext;

  }
```

Putting

```
    final long windowStartTimestamp = DateTimeUtils.thisHourStart();
    log.info("Putting commandId in store: {} {}", commandId, windowStartTimestamp);
    commandIdStore.put(commandId, commandId, windowStartTimestamp);
```

Transform

```
.transformValues(ValueTransformerSupplier<YYY,
                    ? extends XXX>) CommandIdValidator::new,
                COMMAND_ID_STORE);
```

Transformer

```
@Slf4j
public class CommandIdValidator<T extends GeneratedMessageV3> implements
    ValueTransformer<T, XXX<T>> {

  WindowStore<String, String> commandIdStore;

  @Override
  public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
    commandIdStore = (WindowStore<String, String>) context.getStateStore(COMMAND_ID_STORE);
  }

  @Override
  public XXX<T> transform(T command) {

    log.debug("Validating commandId.");

    String commandId = getCommandId(command);

    if (CommandIdValidationUtils.isCommandIdDuplicate(commandId, commandIdStore)) {
      log.warn("Command duplicate detected. Command id " + commandId);
      return new XXX(command,
          XXX.duplicatedCommandId(commandId, command.getClass().getName()));
    } else {
      log.debug("CommandId: {} is not a duplicate.", commandId);
      CommandIdValidationUtils.putCommandIdInStore(commandId, commandIdStore);
      return XXX.successful(command);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has turned out to be a bug and has been fixed in the subsequent versions:
[KAFKA-9891](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9891)

Answer (score 0):

What you describe certainly sounds like a bug in Kafka Streams.

> We rolled back to kafka clients 2.3.1 and the problem persists.

From which version? `2.4.0`? `2.4.1` and `2.5.0` were release recently, can you maybe try it out to see if the problem is still there? (Some EOS bugs got fixed; I could not find a ticket that would match the problem you describe though... So not sure if the bug is still there or not.)

How EOS is supposed to work:

For local RocksDB instances, Kafka Streams also writes a "checkpoint" file to local disk with some metadata. If the checkpoint file exists, we know that RocksDB is "clean", i.e., in-sync with the changelog topic. If the checkpoint file does not exist we know that the state is corrupted and the whole RocksDB instance is wipes out on startup and the state is rebuild from the changelog. Hence, the checkpoint file should only be written during a clean task shutdown (i.e., rebalance) and it should be deleted after a task was assigned and before processing begins. During processing there should be no checkpoint file and thus if we crash, we know that the store is corrupted and we rebuild it from the changelog.

One theory what could be the bug is as follows: when the first thread crashes (on instance A), no checkpoint file is written, what is correct. After the first rebalance, a StandbyTask is assigned to instance A -- this StandbyTask is supposed to wipe out the local state store (as there is no checkoint file) and the bug is that this wipe does not happen (maybe you can verify via the logs; the wipe out should be logged, or maybe some "create file" timestamps on the file system help). When the second thread on instance B crashes, another rebalance is triggered. The StandbyTask incorrectly thinks that it has a clean state and writes the checkpoint file. When the active task starts up on the other thread on instance A, it would just take the corrupted state as the (incorrectly) existing checkpoint file indicates that the state is consistent.

- When you switch to in-memory store, the problem goes away natively, as there is no local state on disk and no checkpoint files and thus state is always rebuild from the changelog topic.
- When you disable StandbyTasks, in the second rebalance no checkpoint file is written and thus when the active task starts up on the second thread in instance A, it now wipes out the store correctly and rebuilds from the changelog.

Maybe you could try to verify this and also maybe open a bug report?

Comment: We tested both 2.4.1 and 2.3.1. Didn't test 2.5.0 although I also haven't found any related ticket.

Comment: I included the logs you asked for in EDIT 2. Seems that on NODE_3 there's a standby task 1_2 running on T-2, it replicates a first valid command, thus creating a checkpoint file. Invalid command causes an error on NODE_1, then NODE_3 T-2 takes over the task. It finds the checkpoint file (which is fine), and starts to process the invalid command. It crashes, same node T-1 takes over, finds the checkpoint file (!), thinks state store is clean (apparently it's not as it contains state modified by T-2) and finds a duplicated command id. Makes sense?

Comment: I also created a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9891